# Monitoring replication on CouchDB with CouchBase Lite

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

I have this info about my datable:

> {"db_name":"my_table","doc_count":386321,"doc_del_count":112331,"update_seq":3585223,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":10083242115,"data_size":1029825313,"instance_start_time":"1533006878496574","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":3585328}

About that Json I have been reading on [CouchDB](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/common.html) site that:

> 1. doc_count (number) – A count of the documents in the specified database.
> 2. doc_del_count (number) – Number of deleted documents

I am logging the replication itself and using `getCompletedChangesCount()` method over a replicator I getting always more than `doc_count` number , so my question is .
Does the replication process replicate the `doc_del_count` ? In afirmative case? Why? Can I skip those `doc_del_count` in the replication process? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was mostly answered in [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127024/doc-del-count-bigger-than-doc-count-on-couchdb).  The short version is you need to track deleted documents, so the count gets added in.

Normally deleted documents have all properties removed, so the overhead is very small.  You can use a deleted document as a kind of archive with a set of properties, although that must be done explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Hod , just one question how Can I avoid to download those documents in the replication process, filter with  if (doc._deleted === true) return false;  does not work in case

Comment: Currently I think not all filtering works with CouchDB.  See if this helps (you may want to look at the connected Github issue): https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html#filtered-pull-from-couchdb-pouchdb-or-cloudant