# 'doc_del_count' bigger than 'doc_count' on CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchbase-lite

I have just received  an Android project that works with `CouchDB` and `CouchBase Lite`.

The first step in the app is a replication, more or less the replication spent more than 2 hours, but usually it never finish.

On the dataBase site I can see that doc_del_count is bigger than doc_count, It does not make sense because we never delete documents.
[image]

In this case the replication process handles 519695 documents and 498264 of them are deleted, so it is crazy

My questions are:
Why replication download `doc_del_count` if they are deleted documents?
How Can I see those deleted documents?
Can I removed all those `doc_del_count`? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why replication download doc_del_count if they are deleted documents?

Because deleted documents are never truly deleted in CouchDB. Instead, the `_deleted` field is set to `true`.  This is primarily to allow proper synchronization where updates can happen in more than one place.  Imagine that a document is deleted from one place, but updated to include new information in another.  Which operation should take priority? CouchDB has no way of knowing, so it keeps both versions around, and lets the application designer handle conflict resolution as they see fit.

> How Can I see those deleted documents?

Consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854883/retrieve-just-deleted-document) for details, but the short answer is: include `revs_info=true` in your query per [the documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/document/common.html).

> Can I removed all those doc_del_count? How?

You can [compact](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/compact.html) the database, but this won't remove deleted documents, for reasons explained above.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Flimzy I am getting a lot of troubles replicating 519695 documents

Comment: @JeCuRo: Depending on your use case, [filtered replication](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication) might be an option for you.

Comment: Yes I tried it, I have a filter that says: " just take documents for the device number 22  and 84" but nothing changes and still waiting hours for the replication  ---- "filters": {
       "22": "function(doc, req) { if( 22 == doc.device_num )return true; if( 84 == doc.device_num )return true; return false; }",

Comment: @JeCuRo If you want to filter out deleted documents, you should use a filter that excludes `_deleted: true`.

Comment: gracias amigo, also tried :(  "22":  if( 22 == doc.device_num )return true;if (doc._deleted)return false; if( 84 == doc.device_num )return true; return false; }",       but in this case I got and error in the replication and the replication stops